# SSH Jump Host and move to a specific directory

Tags: linux, ssh

I need to concatenete a `cd` command with an `ssh` jump host:

```
:~$ ssh -tt -C -X user1@server ssh -tt -C -X user2@host "cd ~/my/work/directory ; bash"
```

but I get the following error:

```
bash: line 0: cd: /home/user1/my/work/directory: No such file or directory
Connection to host closed.
```

Seems that ssh try to move to `/my/work/directory` in the server machine. So I tried to substitue `~/` with the full path `/home/user2` but, I get the same error:

```
Connection to host closed.
```

In both cases ssh bring me from the client home directory to the server home directory. I also tried to jump host in two different steps (client -> server server -> host) and it works. It seems that the `cd` step was done in the first ssh (client -> server) instead of the second one (server -> host).

Do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first ssh is interpreting this as a list of two separate commands it should run. Your ssh session on `server` is first executing `ssh -tt -C -X user2@host` which exits immediately and then running `cd ~/my/work/directory ; bash`.  What you need to do is quote the whole everything from the start of the second ssh to the end of the command so it gets treated as a single thing.

`ssh -tt -C -X user1@server 'ssh -tt -C -X user2@host "cd ~/my/work/directory ; bash"'`

That way when you ssh into `server` it will execute `ssh -tt -C -X user2@host "cd ~/my/work/directory ; bash"` as a whole command instead of breaking it into parts.